# Make part of a line dashed in chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

This is my goal:
a line graph where for x<10, the line is dashed, and for x>=10, it's a solid line.

I know one way to do it is to have two datasets, one with null values for x>=10, and another one with null values for x<10. However, this solution seems too hacky and also at the joint point (x=10), the tooltip will show two lines.
Is there any way to do this in a clean way?